# Toggle width of a container using jQuery

Tags: jquery, width, toggle, containers, forum

I am working on a theme for MyBB forum software.
I want to add a feature where the width is expanded from fixed 1000px of the container to a fluid width 85% and viceversa ith slow animation using jQuery.
I want to have a toggle button which says expand - shrink buttons.
The container also should support cookies so when user reloads the page , it would be of same width he chose.
I tried many solutions from Stackoverflow and over web but in vain.
Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
regards

Here is the code :

Hello i figured it out .... the jquery toggle , but i want to add cookie to it.
here is the code

> $(document).ready( function(){ 
> $('#toggle-button').click( function() { 
> var toggleWidth = $("#container").width() == 960 ? "85%" : "960px"; 
> $('#container, .wrap').animate({ width: toggleWidth }); 
> }); 
> });

Thanks :)

Comment: please add the sample code so i can help you.

Comment: Hello i figured it out .... the jquery toggle , but i want to add cookie to it.
here is the code 
> <div id="toggle-button"></div>
> <div id="#container></div>

>  $(document).ready( function(){ <br />
>    $('#toggle-button').click( function() { <br />
>        var toggleWidth = $("#container").width() == 960 ? "85%" : "960px"; <br />
>        $('#container, .wrap').animate({ width: toggleWidth }); <br />
>    }); <br />
> });

Thanks :)

Comment: Edited the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code as per your requirement so try this code:
HTML

```
<div id="container">this is container div</div>
<div class="wrp">this is wrp div</div>
<input type="button" value="toggle" id="toggle-button">
```

CSS

```
#container {
   width:960px;
   background-color: red;
}
.wrp {
    width:1000px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var setWidth = $.cookie("width");
    if (typeof setWidth !== "undefined" && setWidth == "85%") {
        $('#container,.wrp').width(setWidth); // 85% width set using cookie
    } else if (typeof setWidth !== "undefined" && setWidth == "960px") {
        $('#container,.wrp').width(setWidth); // 960px,1000px(for wrp) width set using cookie
    }
    $('#toggle-button').click(function () {
        var toggleWidth = $("#container").width() == 960 ? "85%" : "960px";

        $('#container, .wrp').animate({
            width: toggleWidth
        });
        $.cookie('width', toggleWidth);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/844ee/)

**Note:** you have to include **jquery.cookie.min.js** into your file for cookie to get work